# PowerShell remote execution between two Linux servers

Tags: linux, powershell

I have the PowerShell scripts (.ps1) on my Centos server. I can successfully execute them locally, but don’t know how I can execute these scripts remotely from another Centos server.
I’ve tried to execute scripts after connecting over SSH and I’m getting errors
`-command not found` and `-syntax error`.

How to run PowerShell scripts on Linux remotely from another Linux box?

Comment: You might find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6 to be of interest.

Comment: Please show the full command you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply ssh to the PowerShell server and run your `.ps1` scripts from the console like this: `pwsh your_script.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I'm using:

- ssh to the server: `ssh user@server_name`
- navigate to the scripts directory
- run `pwsh script_name.ps1`

I don't need to connect with PowerShell session and didn't do any configuration on PowerShell server. Hope it helps.